# iReport runs in linux terminal but no with PHP exec command

Tags: php, linux, apache, jasper-reports

I'm having problems executing the next command in a PHP file:

```
$cmd = '-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/opt/lampp/htdocs/crm2/modules/zr2_Report/jasper/log4j.properties -classpath
"custom/ZuckerReports2/resources/:custom/ZuckerReports2/resources/areas_negocio.jasper_files/:modules/zr2_Report/jasper/jasperreports-javaflow-5.1.2.jar:
modules/zr2_Report/jasper/zuckerreports-1.0.jar:modules/zr2_Report/jasper/commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar:
modules/zr2_Report/jasper/batik-anim.jar:modules/zr2_Report/jasper/bcel-5.2.jar:
modules/zr2_Report/jasper/barcode4j-2.0.jar:
modules/zr2_Report/jasper/ant-1.7.1.jar:
modules/zr2_Report/jasper/jasperreports-applet-5.1.2.jar:
modules/zr2_Report/jasper/batik-css.jar:
modules/zr2_Report/jasper/servlet.jar:modules/zr2_Report/jasper/commons-digester-1.7.jar:
modules/zr2_Report/jasper/batik-awt-util.jar:modules/zr2_Report/jasper/jasperreports-5.1.2.jar:
modules/zr2_Report/jasper/antlr-2.7.5.jar:modules/zr2_Report/jasper/xml-apis-ext.jar:
modules/zr2_Report/jasper/poi-3.6.jar:modules/zr2_Report/jasper/iText-2.1.7.jar:
modules/zr2_Report/jasper/jxl-2.6.10.jar:modules/zr2_Report/jasper/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar:
modules/zr2_Report/jasper/batik-gvt.jar:modules/zr2_Report/jasper/spring-beans-2.5.5.jar:
modules/zr2_Report/jasper/mysql-connector-java-3.1.11-bin.jar:
modules/zr2_Report/jasper/batik-parser.jar:modules/zr2_Report/jasper/batik-util.jar:
modules/zr2_Report/jasper/hibernate3.jar:modules/zr2_Report/jasper/groovy-all-1.7.5.jar:
modules/zr2_Report/jasper/barbecue-1.5-beta1.jar:modules/zr2_Report/jasper/jcommon-1.0.15.jar:
modules/zr2_Report/jasper/jasperreports-functions-5.1.2.jar:
modules/zr2_Report/jasper/log4j-1.2.15.jar:modules/zr2_Report/jasper/saaj-api-1.3.jar:
modules/zr2_Report/jasper/jpa.jar:modules/zr2_Report/jasper/jfreechart-1.0.12.jar:
modules/zr2_Report/jasper/spring-core-2.5.5.jar:modules/zr2_Report/jasper/mondrian-3.1.1.12687.jar:
modules/zr2_Report/jasper/hsqldb-1.8.0-10.jar:modules/zr2_Report/jasper/batik-script.jar:
modules/zr2_Report/jasper/serializer.jar:modules/zr2_Report/jasper/commons-collections-2.1.1.jar:
modules/zr2_Report/jasper/batik-svggen.jar:modules/zr2_Report/jasper/batik-dom.jar:
modules/zr2_Report/jasper/rhino-1.7R1.jar:modules/zr2_Report/jasper/batik-ext.jar:
modules/zr2_Report/jasper/joda-time-1.2.1.jar:modules/zr2_Report/jasper/xml-apis.jar:
modules/zr2_Report/jasper/batik-bridge.jar:modules/zr2_Report/jasper/xercesImpl-2.7.0.jar:
modules/zr2_Report/jasper/TestZucker.jar:modules/zr2_Report/jasper/batik-svg-dom.jar:
modules/zr2_Report/jasper/jasperreports-fonts-5.1.2.jar:modules/zr2_Report/jasper/jdt-compiler-3.1.1.jar:
modules/zr2_Report/jasper/xalan-2.7.1.jar:modules/zr2_Report/jasper/png-encoder-1.5.jar:
modules/zr2_Report/jasper/bsh-2.0b4.jar:modules/zr2_Report/jasper/batik-xml.jar:
modules/zr2_Report/jasper/jaxen-1.1.1.jar:modules/zr2_Report/jasper/commons-javaflow-20060411.jar"
at.go_mobile.zuckerreports.JasperBatchMain custom/ZuckerReports2/temp/4f558394-298d-4783-4600-51e812a588ef/cmd.properties 2>&1'; 
exec($cmd,$out,$res);
```

The result of this execution is this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.<init>(JRBaseFiller.java:121)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:88)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:103)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:61)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createFiller(JRFiller.java:153)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:55)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fillReport(JRFiller.java:170)
    at at.go_mobile.zuckerreports.JasperBatchMain.main(JasperBatchMain.java:126)
Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Problem reading font data.
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontFace.<init>(SimpleFontFace.java:108)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontFace.<init>(SimpleFontFace.java:128)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontFace.getInstance(SimpleFontFace.java:67)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontFamily.setNormal(SimpleFontFamily.java:99)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionHelper.parseFontFamily(SimpleFontExtensionHelper.java:261)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionHelper.parseFontFamilies(SimpleFontExtensionHelper.java:232)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionHelper.loadFontFamilies(SimpleFontExtensionHelper.java:193)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionHelper.loadFontFamilies(SimpleFontExtensionHelper.java:162)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.FontExtensionsRegistry.getExtensions(FontExtensionsRegistry.java:56)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry.getExtensions(DefaultExtensionsRegistry.java:110)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStyledTextParser.<clinit>(JRStyledTextParser.java:83)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Problem reading font data.
    at java.awt.Font.createFont0(Font.java:999)
    at java.awt.Font.createFont(Font.java:876)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontFace.<init>(SimpleFontFace.java:100)
    ... 18 more
```

However, when I run the command directly in a linux terminal, the report is generated right.

These are the lines from the log4j log file:

```
11:05:39,673 DEBUG ExtensionsEnvironment,main:78 - Instantiating extensions registry class net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry
11:05:39,683 DEBUG DefaultExtensionsRegistry,main:130 - Loading registries for cache key sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@1b0620c
11:05:39,684 DEBUG JRLoader,main:873 - Found resource jasperreports_extension.properties at jar:file:/opt/lampp/htdocs/crm2/modules/zr2_Report/jasper/jasperreports-javaflow-5.1.2.jar!/jasperreports_extension.properties in classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@1b0620c
11:05:39,685 DEBUG JRLoader,main:873 - Found resource jasperreports_extension.properties at jar:file:/opt/lampp/htdocs/crm2/modules/zr2_Report/jasper/jasperreports-5.1.2.jar!/jasperreports_extension.properties in classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@1b0620c
11:05:39,685 DEBUG JRLoader,main:873 - Found resource jasperreports_extension.properties at jar:file:/opt/lampp/htdocs/crm2/modules/zr2_Report/jasper/jasperreports-functions-5.1.2.jar!/jasperreports_extension.properties in classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@1b0620c
11:05:39,686 DEBUG JRLoader,main:873 - Found resource jasperreports_extension.properties at jar:file:/opt/lampp/htdocs/crm2/modules/zr2_Report/jasper/jasperreports-fonts-5.1.2.jar!/jasperreports_extension.properties in classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@1b0620c
11:05:39,695 DEBUG DefaultExtensionsRegistry,main:158 - Loading JasperReports extension properties resource jar:file:/opt/lampp/htdocs/crm2/modules/zr2_Report/jasper/jasperreports-javaflow-5.1.2.jar!/jasperreports_extension.properties
11:05:39,697 DEBUG DefaultExtensionsRegistry,main:208 - Instantiating registry of type net.sf.jasperreports.engine.style.PropertyStyleProviderExtensionFactory for property net.sf.jasperreports.extension.registry.factory.property.style.provider
11:05:39,697 DEBUG DefaultExtensionsRegistry,main:233 - Instantiating extensions registry for property.style.provider using factory class net.sf.jasperreports.engine.style.PropertyStyleProviderExtensionFactory
11:05:39,699 DEBUG DefaultExtensionsRegistry,main:208 - Instantiating registry of type net.sf.jasperreports.components.headertoolbar.HeaderToolbarConditionalStyleProviderExtensionFactory for property net.sf.jasperreports.extension.registry.factory.header.toolbar.style.provider
11:05:39,700 DEBUG DefaultExtensionsRegistry,main:233 - Instantiating extensions registry for header.toolbar.style.provider using factory class net.sf.jasperreports.components.headertoolbar.HeaderToolbarConditionalStyleProviderExtensionFactory
11:05:39,701 DEBUG DefaultExtensionsRegistry,main:208 - Instantiating registry of type net.sf.jasperreports.components.headertoolbar.HeaderToolbarParameterContributorExtensionFactory for property net.sf.jasperreports.extension.registry.factory.header.toolbar.parameter.contributor
11:05:39,701 DEBUG DefaultExtensionsRegistry,main:233 - Instantiating extensions registry for header.toolbar.parameter.contributor using factory class net.sf.jasperreports.components.headertoolbar.HeaderToolbarParameterContributorExtensionFactory
11:05:39,702 DEBUG DefaultExtensionsRegistry,main:208 - Instantiating registry of type net.sf.jasperreports.governors.GovernorExtensionsRegistryFactory for property net.sf.jasperreports.extension.registry.factory.governor
11:05:39,703 DEBUG DefaultExtensionsRegistry,main:233 - Instantiating extensions registry for governor using factory class net.sf.jasperreports.governors.GovernorExtensionsRegistryFactory
11:05:39,704 DEBUG DefaultExtensionsRegistry,main:208 - Instantiating registry of type net.sf.jasperreports.web.util.ContentTypeMappingExtensionsRegistryFactory for property net.sf.jasperreports.extension.registry.factory.content.type.mapping
11:05:39,704 DEBUG DefaultExtensionsRegistry,main:233 - Instantiating extensions registry for content.type.mapping using factory class net.sf.jasperreports.web.util.ContentTypeMappingExtensionsRegistryFactory
11:05:39,706 DEBUG DefaultExtensionsRegistry,main:208 - Instantiating registry of type net.sf.jasperreports.data.DefaultDataAdapterServiceExtensionsRegistryFactory for property net.sf.jasperreports.extension.registry.factory.data.adapter.services
11:05:39,706 DEBUG DefaultExtensionsRegistry,main:233 - Instantiating extensions registry for data.adapter.services using factory class net.sf.jasperreports.data.DefaultDataAdapterServiceExtensionsRegistryFactory
11:05:39,709 DEBUG DefaultExtensionsRegistry,main:208 - Instantiating registry of type net.sf.jasperreports.web.util.JacksonMappingExtensionsRegistryFactory for property net.sf.jasperreports.extension.registry.factory.jackson.mapping
11:05:39,709 DEBUG DefaultExtensionsRegistry,main:233 - Instantiating extensions registry for jackson.mapping using factory class net.sf.jasperreports.web.util.JacksonMappingExtensionsRegistryFactory
11:05:39,710 DEBUG DefaultExtensionsRegistry,main:208 - Instantiating registry of type net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.SQLQueryClauseFunctionsExtensions for property net.sf.jasperreports.extension.registry.factory.sql.clause.functions
11:05:39,710 DEBUG DefaultExtensionsRegistry,main:233 - Instantiating extensions registry for sql.clause.functions using factory class net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.SQLQueryClauseFunctionsExtensions
11:05:39,719 DEBUG DefaultExtensionsRegistry,main:208 - Instantiating registry of type net.sf.jasperreports.components.ComponentsExtensionsRegistryFactory for property net.sf.jasperreports.extension.registry.factory.components
11:05:39,720 DEBUG DefaultExtensionsRegistry,main:233 - Instantiating extensions registry for components using factory class net.sf.jasperreports.components.ComponentsExtensionsRegistryFactory
11:05:39,746 DEBUG DefaultExtensionsRegistry,main:208 - Instantiating registry of type net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistryFactory for property net.sf.jasperreports.extension.registry.factory.default
11:05:39,746 DEBUG DefaultExtensionsRegistry,main:233 - Instantiating extensions registry for default using factory class net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistryFactory
11:05:39,748 DEBUG DefaultExtensionsRegistry,main:208 - Instantiating registry of type net.sf.jasperreports.repo.DefaultRepositoryExtensionsRegistryFactory for property net.sf.jasperreports.extension.registry.factory.repository
11:05:39,748 DEBUG DefaultExtensionsRegistry,main:233 - Instantiating extensions registry for repository using factory class net.sf.jasperreports.repo.DefaultRepositoryExtensionsRegistryFactory
11:05:39,749 DEBUG DefaultExtensionsRegistry,main:208 - Instantiating registry of type net.sf.jasperreports.util.CastorMappingExtensionsRegistryFactory for property net.sf.jasperreports.extension.registry.factory.castor.mapping
11:05:39,749 DEBUG DefaultExtensionsRegistry,main:233 - Instantiating extensions registry for castor.mapping using factory class net.sf.jasperreports.util.CastorMappingExtensionsRegistryFactory
11:05:39,750 DEBUG DefaultExtensionsRegistry,main:208 - Instantiating registry of type net.sf.jasperreports.types.date.DateRangeQueryClauseExtensions for property net.sf.jasperreports.extension.registry.factory.date.range.clause.functions
11:05:39,751 DEBUG DefaultExtensionsRegistry,main:233 - Instantiating extensions registry for date.range.clause.functions using factory class net.sf.jasperreports.types.date.DateRangeQueryClauseExtensions
11:05:39,754 DEBUG DefaultExtensionsRegistry,main:158 - Loading JasperReports extension properties resource jar:file:/opt/lampp/htdocs/crm2/modules/zr2_Report/jasper/jasperreports-5.1.2.jar!/jasperreports_extension.properties
11:05:39,758 DEBUG DefaultExtensionsRegistry,main:208 - Instantiating registry of type net.sf.jasperreports.engine.style.PropertyStyleProviderExtensionFactory for property net.sf.jasperreports.extension.registry.factory.property.style.provider
11:05:39,766 DEBUG DefaultExtensionsRegistry,main:233 - Instantiating extensions registry for property.style.provider using factory class net.sf.jasperreports.engine.style.PropertyStyleProviderExtensionFactory
11:05:39,766 DEBUG DefaultExtensionsRegistry,main:208 - Instantiating registry of type net.sf.jasperreports.components.headertoolbar.HeaderToolbarConditionalStyleProviderExtensionFactory for property net.sf.jasperreports.extension.registry.factory.header.toolbar.style.provider
11:05:39,767 DEBUG DefaultExtensionsRegistry,main:233 - Instantiating extensions registry for header.toolbar.style.provider using factory class net.sf.jasperreports.components.headertoolbar.HeaderToolbarConditionalStyleProviderExtensionFactory
11:05:39,767 DEBUG DefaultExtensionsRegistry,main:208 - Instantiating registry of type net.sf.jasperreports.components.headertoolbar.HeaderToolbarParameterContributorExtensionFactory for property net.sf.jasperreports.extension.registry.factory.header.toolbar.parameter.contributor
11:05:39,767 DEBUG DefaultExtensionsRegistry,main:233 - Instantiating extensions registry for header.toolbar.parameter.contributor using factory class net.sf.jasperreports.components.headertoolbar.HeaderToolbarParameterContributorExtensionFactory
11:05:39,767 DEBUG DefaultExtensionsRegistry,main:208 - Instantiating registry of type net.sf.jasperreports.governors.GovernorExtensionsRegistryFactory for property net.sf.jasperreports.extension.registry.factory.governor
11:05:39,768 DEBUG DefaultExtensionsRegistry,main:233 - Instantiating extensions registry for governor using factory class net.sf.jasperreports.governors.GovernorExtensionsRegistryFactory
11:05:39,768 DEBUG DefaultExtensionsRegistry,main:208 - Instantiating registry of type net.sf.jasperreports.web.util.ContentTypeMappingExtensionsRegistryFactory for property net.sf.jasperreports.extension.registry.factory.content.type.mapping
11:05:39,768 DEBUG DefaultExtensionsRegistry,main:233 - Instantiating extensions registry for content.type.mapping using factory class net.sf.jasperreports.web.util.ContentTypeMappingExtensionsRegistryFactory
11:05:39,768 DEBUG DefaultExtensionsRegistry,main:208 - Instantiating registry of type net.sf.jasperreports.data.DefaultDataAdapterServiceExtensionsRegistryFactory for property net.sf.jasperreports.extension.registry.factory.data.adapter.services
11:05:39,776 DEBUG DefaultExtensionsRegistry,main:233 - Instantiating extensions registry for data.adapter.services using factory class net.sf.jasperreports.data.DefaultDataAdapterServiceExtensionsRegistryFactory
11:05:39,776 DEBUG DefaultExtensionsRegistry,main:208 - Instantiating registry of type net.sf.jasperreports.web.util.JacksonMappingExtensionsRegistryFactory for property net.sf.jasperreports.extension.registry.factory.jackson.mapping
11:05:39,776 DEBUG DefaultExtensionsRegistry,main:233 - Instantiating extensions registry for jackson.mapping using factory class net.sf.jasperreports.web.util.JacksonMappingExtensionsRegistryFactory
11:05:39,776 DEBUG DefaultExtensionsRegistry,main:208 - Instantiating registry of type net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.SQLQueryClauseFunctionsExtensions for property net.sf.jasperreports.extension.registry.factory.sql.clause.functions
11:05:39,776 DEBUG DefaultExtensionsRegistry,main:233 - Instantiating extensions registry for sql.clause.functions using factory class net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.SQLQueryClauseFunctionsExtensions
11:05:39,777 DEBUG DefaultExtensionsRegistry,main:208 - Instantiating registry of type net.sf.jasperreports.components.ComponentsExtensionsRegistryFactory for property net.sf.jasperreports.extension.registry.factory.components
11:05:39,777 DEBUG DefaultExtensionsRegistry,main:233 - Instantiating extensions registry for components using factory class net.sf.jasperreports.components.ComponentsExtensionsRegistryFactory
11:05:39,777 DEBUG DefaultExtensionsRegistry,main:208 - Instantiating registry of type net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistryFactory for property net.sf.jasperreports.extension.registry.factory.default
11:05:39,777 DEBUG DefaultExtensionsRegistry,main:233 - Instantiating extensions registry for default using factory class net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistryFactory
11:05:39,777 DEBUG DefaultExtensionsRegistry,main:208 - Instantiating registry of type net.sf.jasperreports.repo.DefaultRepositoryExtensionsRegistryFactory for property net.sf.jasperreports.extension.registry.factory.repository
11:05:39,778 DEBUG DefaultExtensionsRegistry,main:233 - Instantiating extensions registry for repository using factory class net.sf.jasperreports.repo.DefaultRepositoryExtensionsRegistryFactory
11:05:39,778 DEBUG DefaultExtensionsRegistry,main:208 - Instantiating registry of type net.sf.jasperreports.util.CastorMappingExtensionsRegistryFactory for property net.sf.jasperreports.extension.registry.factory.castor.mapping
11:05:39,778 DEBUG DefaultExtensionsRegistry,main:233 - Instantiating extensions registry for castor.mapping using factory class net.sf.jasperreports.util.CastorMappingExtensionsRegistryFactory
11:05:39,778 DEBUG DefaultExtensionsRegistry,main:208 - Instantiating registry of type net.sf.jasperreports.types.date.DateRangeQueryClauseExtensions for property net.sf.jasperreports.extension.registry.factory.date.range.clause.functions
11:05:39,778 DEBUG DefaultExtensionsRegistry,main:233 - Instantiating extensions registry for date.range.clause.functions using factory class net.sf.jasperreports.types.date.DateRangeQueryClauseExtensions
11:05:39,779 DEBUG DefaultExtensionsRegistry,main:158 - Loading JasperReports extension properties resource jar:file:/opt/lampp/htdocs/crm2/modules/zr2_Report/jasper/jasperreports-functions-5.1.2.jar!/jasperreports_extension.properties
11:05:39,779 DEBUG DefaultExtensionsRegistry,main:208 - Instantiating registry of type net.sf.jasperreports.functions.FunctionsRegistryFactory for property net.sf.jasperreports.extension.registry.factory.functions
11:05:39,779 DEBUG DefaultExtensionsRegistry,main:233 - Instantiating extensions registry for functions using factory class net.sf.jasperreports.functions.FunctionsRegistryFactory
11:05:39,786 DEBUG DefaultExtensionsRegistry,main:158 - Loading JasperReports extension properties resource jar:file:/opt/lampp/htdocs/crm2/modules/zr2_Report/jasper/jasperreports-fonts-5.1.2.jar!/jasperreports_extension.properties
11:05:39,787 DEBUG DefaultExtensionsRegistry,main:208 - Instantiating registry of type net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionsRegistryFactory for property net.sf.jasperreports.extension.registry.factory.simple.font.families
11:05:39,787 DEBUG DefaultExtensionsRegistry,main:233 - Instantiating extensions registry for simple.font.families using factory class net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionsRegistryFactory
```

Comment: The Java exception states there's a problem reading a font file - so either it's not where Java expects it to be (working directory), or it's not allowed to read it (permissions). [`chdir()`](http://php.net/chdir) to the location you were working with in the terminal before the `exec()` call to set the correct working directory and try again. If that fails, it's probably a permissions problem, in which case you need to ensure that the appropriate permissions are set on all the dependent files for the Java program so that the user that PHP is running under can access them as required.

Comment: Thanks @DaveRandom, I just make a test and I think it really is a permission problem. I execute the .php file (php -f test.php) through console and it works right as well. The thing is, the user that PHP is running under has fully permission over the files I detail in the classpath in the command. Is there any other files I should take care?

Comment: Well the exception is complaining about a font file (although unhelpfully it doesn't indicate the path it's trying to read) - so you should make sure that any font files shipped with the package are accessible. The most likely candidate file extensions for font files are .ttf and .otf, but there are [many others](http://www.fileinfo.com/filetypes/font). It looks like everything is under `/opt/lampp/htdocs/crm2/` - so first try `chmod -R 777 /opt/lampp/htdocs/crm2/*` and if that works then tighten up the permissions as necessary.

Comment: I know that the .ttf files are into a file called jasperreports-fonts-5.1.2.jar. And I already tried chmod -R 777 over the /opt/lampp/htdocs/crm2/* directories and files, but there's no change.

Answer (score 0):

Well, finally I found the error, after searching a lot I came to find this post (http://blog.codyjung.com/2011/05/29/problems-with-lampp-and-exec/)

It turns out that lampp uses his own libraries, so I got to override /opt/lampp/lib/libgcc_s.so.1 library with the server one (/lib/libgcc_s.so.1), restart apache, and it works right away.